# Why is $c_p/c_v$ term introduced in adiabatic process?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, adiabatic

In an adiabatic process we know there is no change in enthalpy or basically enthalpy change is zero. which means any external work done the internal energy does equal opposite work so as to keep $dH=0$. which means in adiabatic process the pressure and temperature have to change. but while deriving the equation for adiabatic process why do we say that $cp=cv+R$ when this can only be true for isobaric process where pressure is constant and also we introduce the term $cp/cv$ being a constant value called adiabatic constant, my question is why do we even use cp value here while clearly in  the adiabatic process pressure is not constant.
Where am I going wrong? Am I wrong here because $cp=cv+R$ is true for all processes but I thought it is only true for isobaric process.

Comment: Who says H is constant in an adiabatic process?

Comment: I reformatted that franz

Comment: ohh yeah thanks for correcting my mistakes and clearing my misconceptions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try to clarify a few key points.

1. $c_p=c_v+R$ is an equality between two *state* functions (the specific heat depends on the process connected to the heat transfer, but the final quantity is a function f the state). The two specific heats actually correspond to different processes (isobaric and isochoric). It is wrong to think that the equation is valid *for a specific process*. A more accurate description of the physics underlying the relation is that a change of entropy at constant pressure can be written as the change at constant volume plus an additional term taking care of the variation of the remaining thermodynamic variables. Notice, that, written this way, it is valid only for ideal gases.
2. Enthalpy is a state function depending on entropy *and* pressure (for a closed system). Therefore the variation of enthalpy is zero for an adiabatic **and** isobaric process. The reason for the appearance of enthalpy in connection with this formula is that
   $$
   dH=TdS+Vdp
   $$
   and
   $$
   dU=TdS-pdV
   $$
   Therefore, at constant pressure, the enthalpy change is equal to $TdS=Q_{p,rev}$, while at constant volume $TdS=Q_{v,rev}$, where $Q_{p,rev}$ and $Q_{v,rev}$ are the heat exchanged in a reversible transformation at constant pressure and constant volume respectively.

Comment: Isentropic $\iff$ adiabatic $\iff$ reversible?

Comment: @AlBrown adiabatic means no heat exchange with the surroundings. An isolated system undergoing an adiabatic process is isoentropic and reversible only if there is no internal production of entropy.

Answer (score 2):

“In an adiabatic process we know there is no change in enthalpy or basically enthalpy change is zero.”

**This is untrue**. Adiabatic compression of a real or ideal gas will increase its enthalpy and temperature. (For an ideal gas, enthalpy is a function of temperature.)

People often think enthalpy is the stored thermal energy and only heat flow can increase thermal energy. Neither are exactly right, although the former is close to true and true for ideal. It’s the second one. (Finally, theres often also the idea that $pv$ only changes from work, never heat, also untrue.)

---

“which means any external work done the internal energy does equal opposite work so as to keep =0”.

**This is untrue** for a different reason. Work can be done on the substance or by it, only.

One thing that *is* true: at constant pressure the enthalpy change equals the energy exchanged with the environment by heat.

Comment: "One thing that is true: at constant pressure the enthalpy change equals the energy exchanged with the environment by heat."  This is correct only if the externally applied pressure is equal to the initial equilibrium pressure over the entire path, and a sudden change in external pressure at time zero is not involved.  Otherwise, Q will not be equal to the enthalpy change between the initial and final states.

Comment: @ChetMiller can you say more about that? Something like dynamics creating irreversible changes, or friction losses, (viscosity loss maybe?). Or..?

Comment: What do you find if you solve this for an ideal gas in a cylinder with a massless piston that is in contact with a constant temperature reservoir at the same temperature as the initial temperature of the gas?

Comment: Gotta go Chet. Hold down the fort brother